# Validation schemas in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, doctype

Ok, so I've just installed VS 2012 and found one thing that puzzles me a bit. Validation schemas.

What exactly is `DOCTYPE:XHTML5` and `XHTML5`, and what's the difference between them? There's nothing like XHTML5 doctype as far as I know.

I've tried to do a little research on Google with no success so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XHTML5** refers to [version 5 of the XHTML syntax](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml) and is one of the validation schemes in VisualStudio.

**XHTML5 doctype** refers to an XML serialization of HTML5.

For instance, the following is valid HTML5 but not XHTML5 (notice the absent `</li>`):

```
<ul>
  <li>one
  <li>two
  <li>three
</ul>
```

Comment: Finally an interesting answer, almost deleted the question altogether. Can you tell me, when to use XHTML5 and when XHTML5 DOCTYPE validation scheme?